# No field of R can be resolved

Tags: android

I have a little project and yesterday i tried out the clean function ("Project/clean").
But after the clean no "id" or "layout" can be resolved ("[name] cannot be resolved or is not a field").

I have no idea what I have done wrong, because i have read that this is a good way to clean up your whole project...

Anyone a idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you importing android.R instead of your.package.R?

Comment: if I import your.package.R i get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Check for errors in XML files. The R class is generated after XML is compiled to allow it to talk to Java code. If it can't find R, either the XML didn't build or couldn't build.

Also, make sure you're not importing `com.android.R`. Your project has its own R class: `com.your.package.name.R`.

Comment: The XML files are without any error.
I imported `android.R` , cause `package.name.R` gives me an error?

Comment: There's your issue. ``android.R`` is for using Android system resources. ``package.name.R`` (you should be replacing ``package.name`` with your actual package name) is what you need to import.

Comment: Yea I have replaced this, but it says :
The import suedtirolnews.app.R cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

R.java is regenerated on the next build after every clean. If you don't have "Build Automatically" enabled, try enabling it to start the regeneration right after the clean. Try running the project (or just building it). If that fails, Save the project and restart your IDE.

Comment: "Build Automatically" is enabled, and i also restarted my IDE.
The project cannot be runned, because there are those mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I generally fix resource errors by deleting stuff.  First, delete imports that include `R`.  Next, if the first step didn't help, delete the contents of `/gen/` (but not the directory itself).